# Intelligent life on a Super Io?

Tags: aliens, moons

Would it be possible for a moon that receives a lot of tidal heating from its gas giant parent planet like Io to develop intelligent life? Assuming moon is big enough to support an atmosphere and is in the habitable zone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on a lot of factors before you even get to 'intelligence'.

First, is the world in the 'world' viable for life in the first place:

- Is the celestial body in the 'Goldilocks zone'?
- Is the environment conducive to life?
- Is the environment stable for long periods of time (hundreds of millions, if not billions of years)?
- Asteroid impacts? They aren't exactly 'life-friendly'.

Once life is given a chance, then you need to worry about reasons for certain strains of this life to evolve with all the bells and whistles:

- What is the naturalistic reason that some species favour intelligence in selecting a mate?
- Are the contenders for 'intelligence' survivable enough? I mean, panda bears are cute and all, but lets be real! Without human intervention, they'd die out.

Then, you need to identify what you consider intelligence. Brain size? Elephants have bigger brains than us, but I don't see them in labs conducting experiments. Tool usage? Chimps use tools, but same as the elephants -- no chimp scientists (though we do carry out experiments on them, so they are 'in the lab').

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: TL;DR - Yes, anything is 'possible'. My answer is more geared towards 'is it probable'.

Answer (score 1):

Highly probable. The strong tides will make your planet extremely geologically active. Assuming it is a somewhat earthlike planet, this means lots of volcanic activity and continental drift with land masses forming, breaking up and perhaps reforming again. This will put a lot of selective pressures on any lifeforms and leading to rapid evolution. All of which will increase the likelihood of a sapient species eventually arising.

It would be an interesting planet. If it has a strong magnetic field, taking into account Joe's salutory advice, it should enjoy almost continuous auroral displays.  Considering it is most likely tidal locked to its parent gas giant. Night and day will shift according to the planet's position in its orbit, with auroras most visible during its nights.

If there isn't a strong magnetic field, there may be fluorescence in the upper atmosphere due to the radiation belts. However, because of the radiation, which does provide another energy gradient, this will change the biochemistry of any life on your super-Io significantly and it won't compatible with our molecular biological history. Don't eat the local food it may harm you. Evolution will tend to favour radiation-resist organisms.

Intelligent life is not impossible on super-Io planet. Expect beautiful night skies with the best auroras in the business, the ground will be shaking and quaking with seismic activity, and there will be volcanoes almost everywhere. The perfect place for a vulcanologist on a sabbatical.

Answer (score 0):

Just my observation, adding to the comments by Fayth85,
I am certain that where the ingredients for 'life' exist, i.e. carbon based,
H/N/C/O type organisms will inevitably arise.  Sapient life, however
may be sadly rare.  Consider that many gas giants, Jupiter as example are surrounded by a constant 'sleet' of protons and radiation from the primary star,
deflected by the planets' magnetosphere.  Your proposed moon would need a powerful magnetic field of its own, capable of protecting emerging life.
You may want to look at recent revisions to the famous 'Drake equation'
for a rough idea about these probabilities.